# how to implement minimum heap in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, heap, heapsort

I have to read all the data(integers) from file into the array and then iterate the array to make minimum heap and adding them after the last element of the current heap. After reading into array I have to call `SiftUp()`. on each element.At the end of all the inputs I am trying to print out the first five elements of the min heap array. output gives me the following error.

Error occurs:

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

my program:

```
using namespace std;

int heapSize;
void SiftUp(int arr[], int heapSize);
const int arr_Size=500;
int heapArr[arr_Size];

int main()
{
    int integers;
    string fileName;
    ifstream infile;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file to open :";
    cin >> fileName; 
    infile.open(fileName.c_str()); 

    if(!infile)
    {
        cerr << "An eror occurred while openieng the file.";
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!infile.eof())
    {
        for (int i=0; i<arr_Size; i++)
        {
            infile >> integers;
            heapArr[i]=integers;
            heapSize=i;
            cout << "numbers " << heapArr[i] << endl;
            SiftUp(heapArr[i],heapSize);       // Error: invalid conversion
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    return 0;
}

void SiftUp(int arr[], int heapSize)
{
    int p;

    if (heapSize==1)
        return;
    else p = heapSize/2;

    if (arr[p] > arr[heapSize])
        return;
    else swap (arr[heapSize],arr[p]);

    SiftUp(arr[], p);   // Error : expected primary-expression before ']'

    for (int count =0 ; count <5 ; count ++)
    {
        cout << " at index 1 : " << arr[count] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 99% sure your program is crashing. Try using a debugger to find out why.

Comment: What is `Id`? If it's your program, that returns 1 when it can't find the file you ask for. Are you sure the file exists? If that's not the problem, where are you seeing this error? How do I reproduce it?

Comment: @doctorlove My crystal ball says that's actually `ld`, the linker. Which means that the program doesn't even compile.

Comment: Or compiles, but doesn't link. Where (and how) is `void SiftUp(int,int);` defined and how do you build this?

Comment: My bad, should've said "doesn't even build".

Comment: Glib answer to title: use `std::priority_queue` (and/or it's components `std::push_heap` `std::pop_heap` and  `std::make_heap`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i;
for (i=1; i<arr_Size; i++){
    infile >> integer;
    if(infile.fail())break;
    heapArr[i]=integer;
    SiftUp(i);
}
infile.close();
heapSize=i;
for (int count =1 ; count <=5 ; count ++){
    cout << count  <<" :"<< heapArr[count] << endl;
}

return 0;
}

void SiftUp(int heapSize){
    int p;
    if (heapSize==1) return;
    p = heapSize/2;
    if (heapArr[p] < heapArr[heapSize]) return;
    swap (heapArr[heapSize],heapArr[p]);
    SiftUp(p);
    }
```

Comment: There is no point to use two loops to read file. One would be fine. See my code. It will help.

Comment: Also, there is no need to pass the globally declared arrays into functions. You can directly use them. See my code.

Comment: I have changed the names of variable. You should atleast work by yourself as it seems school assignment to me.

Comment: Try to write code in more efficient way and try to learn how to debug program by yourself. It will work.

Answer (score 3):

Please read this post on chameleon questions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions Now to the current question.

```
void SiftUp(int arr[], int heapSize);
```

Your function expects an array, then an int.

```
SiftUp(heapArr[i],heapSize);
```

You pass an int and an int to your function. The compiler refuses to reinterpret your int as an int* (since doing so would be a terrible idea). Try passing an array and an int to your function.

```
SiftUp(heapArr,heapSize);
```

Here is a reference on C++ arrays. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/